# Jquery & Ruby - Toggle function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Could one kindly advise me why my javascript code is not working

[image]

i am using the gem simple_form, what i am trying to do is:

- when a user clicks on the red box (as displayed in the image) the empty red box image should change to a tick box
- i have 2 css images; img-checkbox-notick.png (none tick box image) & img-checkbox-tick.png (tick box image)

i am using javascript / toggle

> new.html.erb

```
<div class="checkbox custom">
    <%= f.input :remember_me, input_html: { class: 'css-checkbox' }, label_html: { class: 'css-label-notick' }, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
 </div>
```

> javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.css-label-notick').on('click', function (e) {
      $('.css-label-notick').toggleClass(".css-label-tick");
  });
});
```

i have displayed the details of the input within the image highlighted in red

> css file

```
.css-label-notick {
  background: url("img-checkbox-notick.png") no-repeat;
  height: 65px;
}

.css-label-tick {
  background: url("img-checkbox-tick.png") no-repeat;
  height: 65px;
}
```

any advise would be much appreciated - many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using toggleClass method, you don't need to put period(.) in front of the classname.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.css-label-notick').on('click', function (e) {
            $(this).toggleClass("css-label-tick");
        });
    });
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/xno5hb34/3/